# How to assign JavaScript value to a CSS property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element:

```
<div class="page">
        //some contents
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page{
    bottom: 0;
    color: #1f1f21;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Getting screen height with JavaScript:

```
var page_height = screen.height;
alert(page_height);
```

How can I apply this `page_height` value to my `.page` class?

(i.e) I need to set screen height to my `page` class

For example, if `screen.height = 405`

I need to add height property

```
height: 405px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.height()`:

```
$('.page').height(page_height);
```

Comment: Worked :) Thank you..will accept your answer

Comment: @UIDesigner: no idea :/

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/5k06ewm0/)

```js
var page_height = screen.height;
$('.page').height(page_height)
alert(page_height);
```

```css
.page{
    bottom: 0;
    color: #1f1f21;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:500px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
        //some contents
</div>
```